# Adding a default value for the suggestions in typeahead

Tags: typeahead

I wanted to add a default value (All) in the dropdown list of typeahead apart from the suggested value that comes up in the dropdown list when the user types some text in the typeahead textfield.

Any help on this  is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the latest version of [typeahead.js](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js) for Bootstrap 3, then you can add another dataset that always returns the default value you want:

```
$('input').typeahead(null,
    //real dataset
    {
        name: 'real-data',
        source: backend.ttAdapter() //Your current suggestions
    },

    //default dataset - will always be shown in dropdown
    {
        name: 'default-data',
        source: function(query, callback) {
            callback([{value: 'All'}]);
        }
    }
);
```

See [this section](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#datasets) of the docs for more information.

Comment: Why dont you just assing the value like any other text? or use the placeholder parameter?